# Clojure Luminus Migrations - Only one table per migration file

Tags: clojure, luminus

I'm creating a web app with Clojure and Luminus, but when I create a migration file with all the tables I need, it will only create the first. This is my `user-table.up.sql` file:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTable (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   first_name VARCHAR(50),
   last_name VARCHAR(50),
   gender VARCHAR(50),
   email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   password VARCHAR(400),
   time_stamp TIMESTAMP,
   is_active BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE LoginTable (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   user_id INTEGER,
   time_stamp TIMESTAMP
);
```

When I run `lein run migrate`, only the table `UserTable` is created. Is this supposed to work like this? Do I need to create a migration file for each table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using Luminus, you are probably using Migratus. If you want to execute multiple statements in one sql file, read this:

https://github.com/yogthos/migratus#multiple-statements

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, is it advisable to create a migration for each table?

Comment: I don't see why you would have only one table per migration.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let Michiel answer here according your case, to run multiple statements in your migration, separate them with `--;;` in your case:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTable (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   first_name VARCHAR(50),
   last_name VARCHAR(50),
   gender VARCHAR(50),
   email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   password VARCHAR(400),
   time_stamp TIMESTAMP,
   is_active BOOLEAN
);
--;;
CREATE TABLE LoginTable (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   user_id INTEGER,
   time_stamp TIMESTAMP
);
```